# What is the difference in meaning between "an order" and "an ordering"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

What is the difference between "an ordering" used as a noun and "an order" used as a noun too? I have searched and apparently there is no difference.

Can we say, "I made an ordering for that book", just as we can say, "I made an order"?

Comment: I think you difficulty arises from confusion over the use of gerunds and present participles. See if this answer helps you: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152300/gerund-vs-participle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gerund vs Participle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152300/gerund-vs-participle)

Answer (score 3):

The noun "ordering" doesn't work well here.  It means "a particular arrangement in sequence" (a quite different meaning from that of "place an order")

The participle/gerund "ordering" refers to the process or act of placing an order, and not to the order itself.  So you can say "Ordering the book was easy".  It doesn't means "making the order was easy". Again in this sense "ordering" has a different meaning from "order"

Comment: what does it mean "ordering the book was easy"